# Python | SKlearn | PCA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Edit: Thanks for spotting the typo, it should be 60*50, i have corrected the same in the question.

I am stuck on the following problem, After performing PCA on a matrix with 60 observations and 50 variables when i checked the shape of pca component it comes out to be 50*50. Whereas i think it should be 60*50. Same i checked in R, it comes out to be, as per my understanding, 60*50. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong. PFB the code:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.random.randn(20*3*50)
from numpy import *
arr = (arr - mean(arr, axis=0)) / std(arr, axis=0)
arr=arr.reshape(60,50)
arr.shape
#output: (60, 50)

arr[1:20, 2] = 1
arr[21:40, 1] = 2
arr[21:40, 2] = 2
arr[41:60, 1] = 1
arr.shape
#output: (60, 50)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA()
X_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(arr)
pca.components_.shape
#output: (50, 50)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, it was a typo, i have edited and rectified the question

Answer (score 3):

[Look](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) at PCA class in scikit-learn. It tells us that:

> ...if n_components is not set all components are kept:
>
> `n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)`

As far as `pca.components_` returns array of shape `(n_components, n_features)`, there is no confusion.

Comment: It says that if `n_components` is not declared than they forced to be equal to `n_features`  count . Your `n_features` count is 50. So you have 50 rows in your result.

Comment: Number of components are correct that is 50, but the number of rows here should be 60 as per the original data whereas in the output the number of rows reduced to 50.When the same was performed in R. The number of rows comes out to be 60 for each of the principal components.

Comment: `pca.components_.shape` returns array of shape `(n_components, n_features)`. The number of samples is not mentioned here.